# Observer updated / updating not fired

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I created an observer to make some actions whenever a transaction is created / updated / deleted.

It works fine for the created / deleting method, but for some reason the updating and updated methods aren't being fired.

This is my observer:

```
<?php

namespace App\Observers\Finance;

use App\Finance\Account;
use App\Finance\Transaction;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class TransactionObserver implements ShouldQueue
{
    /**
     * The name of the queue the job should be sent to.
     *
     * @var string|null
     */
    public $queue = 'transactions';

    /**
     * Updates account balance
     * 
     * @param Account $Account
     * @param int $amount
     * @param int $old_amount
     */
    public function updateAccountBalance(Account $Account, $amount = 0, $old_amount = 0)
    {
        $newBalance = $Account->balance - ($old_amount * 100) + ($amount * 100);

        $Account->update(['balance' => $newBalance]);
    }

    /**
     * Listen to the Transaction created event.
     *
     * @param  Transaction $Transaction
     * @return void
     */
    public function created(Transaction $Transaction)
    {
        $this->updateAccountBalance($Transaction->account, $Transaction->amount);
    }

    /**
     * Listen to the Transaction updating event.
     *
     * @param  Transaction $Transaction
     * @return void
     */
    public function updating(Transaction $Transaction)
    {
        $this->updateAccountBalance($Transaction->account, 0, $Transaction->amount);
    }

    /**
     * Listen to the Transaction updated event.
     *
     * @param  Transaction $Transaction
     * @return void
     */
    public function updated(Transaction $Transaction)
    {
        $this->updateAccountBalance($Transaction->account, $Transaction->amount);
    }

    /**
     * Listen to the Transaction deleted event.
     *
     * @param  Transaction $Transaction
     * @return void
     */
    public function deleting(Transaction $Transaction)
    {
        $this->updateAccountBalance($Transaction->account, 0, $Transaction->amount);
    }
}
```

and the update method in the controller:

```
    public function update(Request $request, Transaction $transaction)
    {
        if (in_array($transaction->id, Transaction::$nonEditable)) {
            abort(404);
        }

        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required|max:255',
            'account_id' => 'required|exists:accounts,id',
            'season_year' => 'required|integer|exists:seasons,year',
            'finance_category_id' => 'required|integer|exists:finance_categories,id',
            'amount' => 'numeric',
            'date' => 'required|date_format:d/m/Y',
        ]);

        $transaction->update($request->all());;

        flash()->success('האובייקט עודכן בהצלחה');

        return redirect()->route('transactions.index');
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?
Plus, does ShouldQueue work with observers?